# Is possible to develop whole asp.net web form with jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to develop a whole asp.net web form with jquery ajax instead of pagepostback?

If possible can anyone show some tutorials or examples?

eg binding data to form (textbox, dropdownlist, gridview etc.), send data to server, etc.

Thank you for your support and Sorry if my english is not good

Zabahey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a web page or should I say simple HTML markup which can use JQuery or any other Javascript Library to load dynamic content from Database. Yes, you can create dropdown's, checkboxes too, but then you have to be very much efficient in Javascript, HTML and DOM knowledge. Because, you can not debug errors rapidly in this case. Also, you need to 
understand the asynchronous behaviour of browsers too.

Its just a complete different pool of water to swim in.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, if you are doing *that much* with jquery you'll do much better trying MVC, as this allows you to work much closer to the HTML (important when marrying to jquery) and avoids all the cruft that is meaningless with a jquery-centric app. It is also much easier to write the ajax routes.

But to answer the question: I'm sure that would be possible, but it will be easier without webforms adding work for you to undo.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Now I'll try to use asp.net mvc for web application but my company don't have anyone use asp.net mvc and I don't have enough power to change this tradition. but I just always improve my skill.  T_T

Comment: @Zabahey - well, maybe €$¥£==hours will convince them. For a jquery-rich app, webforms is harder=longer=more-expensive

Comment: How to fill gridview using Javascript or Jquery?